# Problemas com url usando thymeleaf

Tags: html, tomcat, thymeleaf

Tenho uma pagina que mostra todos os posts de um blog. Essa pagina possui um objeto postagem que por sua vez possui o atributo  que é uma lista de categorias.

Essa lista de categorias é mostrada na pagina na  forma  links para cada post inserido na pagina para o usuário final. O usuário final pode clicar em um link e então ele é direcionado para uma pagina que contem todos os posts relacioandos com aquele tema do link da categoria.

Quero usar o `th:each`  para montar os links.
Os links são montados, mas de maneira incorreta!!

Eis como ele fica:

```
http://localhost:8084/spring-thymeleaf/categoria/?jpa
```

supondo que o usuário clicou no link "jpa" gerado pelo codigo abaixo:

```
   <div th:each="categoria: ${postagem.categorias}">
          <a  href="#"th:href="@{/categoria/(${categoria.permalink})}">
          <span th:text="${categoria.descricao}"></span></a>
      </div>
```

Quero colocar como valor o conteúdo de `${categoria.permalink}` mas sem ter aquela interrogação famigerada!

Para chegar a esse meu codigo me basei em um exemplo do site proprio Thymeleaf:

```
 <tr th:each="prod : ${prods}" th:class="${prodStat.odd}? 'odd'">
          <td th:text="${prod.name}">Onions</td>
          <td th:text="${prod.price}">2.41</td>
         ...
            <span th:text="${#lists.size(prod.comments)}">2</span> comment/s
            <a href="comments.html" 
               th:href="@{/product/comments(prodId=${prod.id})}" 
               th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(prod.comments)}">view</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

Que gera o seguinte url:

```
http://localhost:8084/gtvg/product/comments?prodId=9
```

Queria que fosse possível usar o seguinte código

```
  <div th:each="categoria: ${postagem.categorias}">
          <a  href="#"th:href="@{/categoria/${categoria.permalink}}">
          <span th:text="${categoria.descricao}"></span></a>
      </div>
```

Mas ele tem a seguinte saida,  quando eu clico no link "jpa":

```
http://localhost:8084/spring-thymeleaf-jsp/categoria/$%7Bcategoria.permalink%7D
```

Aqui esta o trecho do meu controller que trata a requisição:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/categoria/{link}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView postsByCategoria(@PathVariable("link") String link, ModelMap model) {

    List<Postagem> postagens = postagemService.findByCategoria(link);

    model.addAttribute("postagens", postagens);

    return new ModelAndView("posts.html", model);
}
```

O que devo fazer? Já procurei em varios lugares e nada!!

Comment: Aparentemente o `?` está vindo direto do valor de `${categoria.permalink}`. Como esse valor é gerado?

Comment: Tenta utilizar `<a href="#" th:href="@{/categoria/{link}(link=${categoria.permalink})}">`, tem mais na [documentação](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss  Ate que enfim! Ufa! Muito obrigado!!Coloque como resposta compadre!! Ai  fica explicito para quem passar pelo mesmo probleminha!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por padrão, conforme a [documentação](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls), a ferramenta adiciona as variáveis à *query string* da URL. Se desejas incorporar o valor da mesma na URL, utilize a sintaxe `{nomeDaVariavel}`, conforme o terceiro exemplo da documentação supracitada.

Para o seu exemplo, ficaria:

```
<a href="#" th:href="@{/categoria/{link}(link=${categoria.permalink})}">
```

Onde `{link}` é a incorporação da variável na URL.