# Problemas para passar dois parametros na url usando thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, tomcat, thymeleaf

Tenho seguinte metodo no meu controler:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView home(ModelMap model) {

        Page<Postagem> page = postagemService.findByPagination(0, 5);
        model.addAttribute("page", page);
        model.addAttribute("urlPagination", "/page");

        return new ModelAndView("posts.html", model);
    }
```

E a seguinte pagina onde uso o thymeleaf para mostrar os dados:

```
   <div>
          <span th:each="p: ${#numbers.sequence(1,page.totalPages)}" >  

                <span>
                        <a href="#" th:href="@{/page/{p}(p=${p})}" style="text-decoration: none">
                        <span th:text="${p}" class="btn-group btn-lg btn-primary"></span>
                    </a> 
                </span>            

          </span>

    </div>
```

A questão écomo pegar o valor de urlPagination que eu enviei pelo controller e colocar no lugar do trecho **page** nessa url:

```
th:href="@{/page/{p}(p=${p})}"
```

Já postei uma duvida semelhante nesse link [Problemas com url usando thymeleaf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/191696/problemas-com-url-usando-thymeleaf). mas no caso, era apenas um parametro!

Comment: Fazer `th:href="@{{url}/{p}(url=${urlPagination},p=${p})}"` não resolve?

Comment: E `th:href="@{${urlPagination}+'/'+${p}}"`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Seu comentario me ajudou a chegar nesse link:@{/{urlPagination}/{p}( urlPagination=${urlPagination}, p=${p})}  e deu certo!! Obrigado

Comment: Com ele responda a pergunta parceiro!! E de ai uma força se achou essa pergunta interessante, haha... OK?